# How to compile CUnit for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cunit

I am trying to compile cuint for iOS, before that i searched for if there is any cunit library available for iOS. can someone please help me on how to compile cunit source in iOS. I am sure someone might have already done it. I am waiting for reply

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I simply import the cunit src code into xcode, removed some windows related source and it worked for me, It is serving my purpose well.